# Eclipse Egit using remote system to add project with git support

Tags: eclipse, ssh, sftp, egit

I have a Server with SSH access. On this server I have a php/yii project including a git repository (so versioned with git). Is it possible to use the EGit Team Provider (which just works fine for local projects/ .git folders) for those remote projects?

I just get nullpoint exceptions with the wizard (Share project) and cant get EGit to recognize the existing git project.

Maybe could try this by creating a fresh test .git repo on a linux server, add a php file, use eclipse remote system to browse by ssh for the folder containing the .git folder, use right click on that folder->create remote project and then somehow figure out how EGit could be added...

Answer (score 1):

EGIT doesn't recognize the repository if it doesn't end with .git extension

Login to the LINUX server

cd to path in which you want the repository in

mkdir your_project_name.git //This will create the repository

git init --bare //This will actually initialize the git repository

clone this repository

add files in the local repo

add files to index, commit and push to master